# How do I make two functions of a function based views communicate with each other in django?

Tags: django-models, django-views

I am new to Django and working on a project. I have to communicate two functions of views in Django.

> views.py

```
@login_required
def likepost(request,id):
    post = NewPost.objects.get(id = id)
    is_like = False
    for like in post.likepost.all():
        if like == request.user and request.method == "POST":
            is_like = True
            break
    
    if not is_like:
        post.likepost.add(request.user)
    
    else:
        post.likepost.remove(request.user)
    
    return JsonResponse({
        "is_like" : is_like,
    })
```

This is my likepage function which I want to call in my index function. The index function has been given below.

```
def index(request):
    posts = NewPost.objects.all().order_by("-timestamp")
    page = Paginator(posts,3)
    page_req = request.GET.get('page')
    page_view = page.get_page(page_req)
    num = "a" * page_view.paginator.num_pages
    is_like = likepost(posts.id)
    
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "POST":
            post = NewPostForm(request.POST)
            user = request.user
            timestamp = datetime.now()
            if post.is_valid:
                post = post.save(commit=False)
                postdata = NewPost(post=post,user=user,timestamp=timestamp)
                postdata.save()
                # return Response({"message" : "Post created successfully !"})

            return render(request,"network/index.html",{
                "post" : post,
                # "user" : user,
                # "posts" : posts,
                "timestamp" : timestamp,
                "page_view" : page_view,
                "num" : num,
                "is_like" : is_like,
            })
            # JsonResponse(posts, safe=False)

        else:
            post = NewPostForm()
            return render(request,"network/index.html",{
                "post" : post,
                "posts" : posts,
                "page_view" : page_view,
                "num" : num,
                "is_like" : is_like,
            })

    return render(request,"network/index.html",{
        "posts" : posts,
        "page_view" : page_view,
        "num" : num,
        "is_like" : is_like,
    })
```

Although I have `id` attribute in my model, it gives the following error.

[image]

How can I fix it? I want to make a like button.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue you just add user to is_like = likepost(posts.user.id).I think you need to query post by the user id not just the posts.id,so hopefully it should work now.

```
def index(request):
    posts = NewPost.objects.all().order_by("-timestamp")
    page = Paginator(posts,3)
    page_req = request.GET.get('page')
    page_view = page.get_page(page_req)
    num = "a" * page_view.paginator.num_pages
    is_like = likepost(posts.user.id)
    
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "POST":
            post = NewPostForm(request.POST)
            user = request.user
            timestamp = datetime.now()
            if post.is_valid:
                post = post.save(commit=False)
                postdata = NewPost(post=post,user=user,timestamp=timestamp)
                postdata.save()
                # return Response({"message" : "Post created successfully !"})

            return render(request,"network/index.html",{
                "post" : post,
                # "user" : user,
                # "posts" : posts,
                "timestamp" : timestamp,
                "page_view" : page_view,
                "num" : num,
                "is_like" : is_like,
            })
            # JsonResponse(posts, safe=False)

        else:
            post = NewPostForm()
            return render(request,"network/index.html",{
                "post" : post,
                "posts" : posts,
                "page_view" : page_view,
                "num" : num,
                "is_like" : is_like,
            })

    return render(request,"network/index.html",{
        "posts" : posts,
        "page_view" : page_view,
        "num" : num,
        "is_like" : is_like,
    })
```